# File accept and capture tags fails in crosswalk webview

Tags: android, mobile, android-webview, crosswalk-runtime

Im trying to make a picture-upload only input field, in a compact app running basicly a crosswalk webview with some custom scripting to it.

Through a regular browser, using tags like :

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture="camera">
```

or 
`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`
works as intended, taking the user directly to the camera capture mode.

But for some reason, this ResolverActivity panel appears on my device :

[image: This bloody resolver. Make it go away...]

I really want it gone, and take the user straight to taking a photo. My system doens't support video (and even less voice recordings).

I found some bug reports that resonates with what I'm dealing with, but they also state that the bug has been resolved. Alas, when I run the latest version of crosswalk, this bug still appears.

Does anyone have some ideas on how to resolve this? Maybe some manifest files preventing camcorder and audio recording to appear?

I've tried with both **xwalk_core_library_beta:15.44.384.2** and **xwalk_core_library:14.43.343.23**

If nothing else, I'll have to code a manual upload process. Not impossible, but I'd really like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new (2 days) in developing code for Android, so bear with me.
The code is working for me in 4.4.2 with:

> <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

Is messy, but hope will help some one.

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    xWalkWebView=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);
    xWalkWebView.setUIClient(new UIClient(xWalkWebView));
    xWalkWebView.load("http://your.url", null);
}

private ValueCallback<Uri> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;
public static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

class UIClient extends XWalkUIClient {

    public void openFileChooser(XWalkView view, ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFile,
                                String acceptType, String capture) {

        if(!(acceptType.toLowerCase().equals("image/*") && capture.equals("true"))){
            super.openFileChooser(view, uploadFile, acceptType, capture);
            return;
        }


        if(mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = uploadFile;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        } else {
            takePictureIntent = null;
        }


        Intent contentSelectionIntent =new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
       xWalkWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }


    Uri results = null;

    // Check that the response is a good one
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(data == null) {
            // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
            if(mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                results = Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath);
            }
        } else {
            String dataString = data.getDataString();
            if (dataString != null) {
                results = Uri.parse(dataString);
            }
        }
    }

    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
    mFilePathCallback = null;
    return;

}



private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed, and was deployed to beta starting from: `xwalk_core_library_beta:19.49.514.2` (and some earlier canary).
You shouldn't use `capture=camera` if you want to be able to use pictures stored on your phone.